# (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, smtp

I encountered an authentication error while trying to send an email using a POST request. The error message I received is as follows:

"530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError o5-20020a170902c50500b001b8aa51821csm3928889plx.138 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost'"

I am using a POST request to send an email, and it seems that authentication is required for the operation to be successful. The email service provider I am using is Google Mail (Gmail).

Here are the details of the request:

- Request Method: POST

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this authentication issue and successfully send emails using the POST request. Thank you.